# Shift coordinate points to origin

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a set of coordinate points

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xpos = [2419, 2597, 2678, 2691, 2967, 3350, 2227.5, 2781.0, 2278]
ypos = [4687, 4784, 4986, 4479, 4873.5, 3250, 4109, 3329, 3507]
plt.plot(xpos, ypos, '*')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The axes range is from (xmin,ymin) to (xmax, ymax).
I would like to shift the coordinates such that the axes range starts from origin.

Suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: subtract min(xpos) from each xpos and subtract min(ypos) from each ypos and then plot the new values

Comment: Did that :) thanks anyway

Comment: If you did that, what was the result? Or do you just want the axes from 0,0?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbbwt.png)

Comment: No, I shifted all the coordinated by doing what you had also mentioned above `subtract min(xpos) from each xpos and subtract min(ypos)`.

Comment: Then it's not clear what you're trying to do. You should add additional information to your question. Perhaps add a mockup of what you're trying to do.